# Drag and drop issue (Mac)

Tags: macos, javafx-2

I'm getting some problems when running my code, which worked under windows, now that I'm on a mac. This one is related to drag and drop, it used to work on windows (Write once, debug everywhere!) but now the onDragDropped event is not being fired (I've tested using System.out.println()). Here's the code. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
    HRWindowGridPane.setOnDragEntered(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {


        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Drag entered");
            lblPhoto.setEffect(finalBlend);
            event.consume();
        }
    });

    HRWindowGridPane.setOnDragExited(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            lblPhoto.setEffect(null);
            System.out.println("Drag exited");
            event.consume();
        }
    });

    EventHandler<DragEvent> onDragOver = new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            /* data is dragged over the target */
            /* accept it only if it is not dragged from the same node 
             * and if it has a string data */
            if (event.getGestureSource() != HRWindowGridPane &&
                    event.getDragboard().hasFiles()) {
                /* allow for both copying and moving, whatever user chooses */
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
                System.out.println("Drag over");
            }

            event.consume();
        }
    };
    HRWindowGridPane.setOnDragOver(onDragOver);

    HRWindowGridPane.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() 
    {

        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent event) 
        {
            System.out.println("Drag dropping");
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            System.out.println("Drag dropped: got dragboard from event!");

            if(db.hasFiles())
            {
                System.out.println("Drag dropped: dragboard has files!");
                 for(File file:db.getFiles())
                 {
                     if(file.getName().contains(".jpg") ||  file.getName().contains(".jpeg") || file.getName().contains(".JPG"))
                     {
                        Image img;
                        try
                        {
                            System.out.println("Everything is fine until image processing... hmmm");
                            img = new Image(file.toURI().toURL().toString(), 118.0, 88.0, false, true);
                            ImageView view = new ImageView(img);
                            view.setFitWidth(118.0);
                            view.setFitHeight(88.0);
                            view.resize(118.0, 88.0);
                            lblPhoto.setGraphic(view);
                            avatarImage = file;
                        } 
                        catch (IOException e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                     }
                     else
                     {
                         AlertWindow alert = new AlertWindow("Falha", "O Arquivo não é uma imagem JPG válida");
                         try 
                         {
                            Stage stage = new Stage();

                            alert.start(stage);

                            stage.toFront();
                            HRWindowGridPane.toBack();
                            stage.centerOnScreen();
                            stage.show();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                     }

                 }


            }

            event.setDropCompleted(true);
            event.consume();
        }

    });

    HRWindowGridPane.setOnDragDone(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent event) 
        {
            System.out.println("Drag done");
        }
    });
```

More info about the system:

```
Brunos-MacBook-Pro:~ bruno$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_04"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-b21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0-b21, mixed mode)
```

Javafx version 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at jira now as a bug. Here's the link I got from another forum, hope it's fixed when 2.2 is ga.

http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-20253

**EDIT**

To keep this answer updated. The Drag and Drop issue was addressed when `JavaFX-2` went GA. It work's like a charm on MacOS X with jre 1.7+